# 1993 Triton Diesel 4x4

Tags: transmission

Wondering if there was a common fix such as a gearbox or diff swap to bring the cruising revs down on a 1993 diesel Triton. currently revs in 3000 rpm range at 100k/hr hoping to bring down about 500 or so.

Comment: 500 is way to low for that engine.

Comment: I think he meant reduce by 500; 2500 rpm @ 100kph.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the diffs on my Landrover: the original were 4.7 to 1 and changed to 3.54 to 1...

All I needed were the complete diffs as they just bolted into the existing axle. Yours may well be different - if you need to change the crown wheel and pinion then that is more work but still possible. You will need to check what axles are used and find if there were different ratios available.

Another, or third, possibility is to change the size of the tires... But that will also affect the handling characteristics which you may not want.